# Will Keras fit( ) function automatically shuffles the input dataset by default?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras

I am asking [this](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) model fit( ) function.

```
fit(x=array_x, y=array_y, batch_size=32, epochs=10)
```

The question is straightforward:

Whether fit( ) will **automatically** **shuffle** the input dataset? (array_x, array_y in this case)

I ask this question because I find my fit( ) and fit_generator( ) has different outputs, with same input. My generator feeds inputs to fit_generator( ) in order. I guess the reason is about shuffle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, by default it does shuffle.**

Here is the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method).

The default call signature:

```
fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None,
    validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, 
    lass_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0,
    steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1,
    ax_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False)
```

where the description for `shuffle` is:

> shuffle: Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch) or str (for 'batch'). This argument is ignored when x is a generator. 'batch' is a special option for dealing with the limitations of HDF5 data; it shuffles in batch-sized chunks. Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not None.

This means ***it will not shuffle*** if you have set a value for `steps_per_epoch`.